# java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.Session cannot be cast to javax.mail.Session

Tags: java, tomcat

I have been receiving this error when trying to run the following code to get a javax.mail.Session object using a tomcat context file.

```
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        Session session = (javax.mail.Session) envCtx.lookup("mail/session");
```

This is the resource declaration in the context.xml.

```
  <Resource name="mail/Session" auth="Container"
        type="javax.mail.Session"
        mail.smtp.host="host"
        mail.smtp.user="user"
        mail.smtp.password="password"
        mail.smtp.auth="false"/>
```

I understand this can be due to me having the same library for the javax.mail.Session in my application server library(tomcat) folder and in my applications library folder, i have eliminated as many duplicate library files from my application library folder (e.g. mail.jar) that i can see have the javax.mail.Session as part of the library, now i am at a point where i am a still getting this error and not sure what other libraries could be the source of this problem, or is it some other issue that i am not aware of?

What would people suggest i do to find the source of this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you restart tomcat. If the exception is still thrown, you have missed a place where javax.mail.Session is still in.

Comment: I don't know the exact solution for your problem, but one more reason it may occur (for you to dig into) - the javax.mail.Session is loaded by 2 different classloaders

Answer (score 22):

This problem occurs in the server because the lib of Tomcat and you application both have their own copy of `mail.jar` (in WEB-INF/lib), so the classloaders can load two different Session.If you delete the `mail.jar`from your application, this problem will be solved.

Comment: Another situation: when  using Maven, the conflicting mail.jar could be imported using an indirect dependency on one of the direct dependencies in the pom. In this case you have to hunt down the indirect dependency and use an 'exclusions/exclusion' to prevent the indirect dependency from being included.

Answer (score 9):

You're probably no longer having this issue, but for the next person to come here:

If you're using maven, add `<scope>provided</scope>` to your javax.mail dependency in pom.xml.

For instance, in my case:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>YOUR_VERSION</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!-- This line is new -->
</dependency>
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: I had to restart Tomcat and redeploy my application for it to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

use provided scope in maven 
    
                javax.mail
                mail
                1.4
                provided

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the mail.jar in the lib of your server,  delete the it from your application / pom file , this problem will be solved.